# Injecting a service inside of TimerTask

Tags: cdi, timertask

I need to run daily a process in order to do maintenance work on the server (update records).

I have a singleton scope class that runs a timer and an inner class with the injection of the service I need. When I run the programm the timer throws a NullPointerException because the service has not been injected.

```java
@Named("demonService")
@Singleton
public class DemonImpl implements IDemonService
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DemonioImpl.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        log.info("-->Demon");

        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();//Every day at 2:00am (from now)
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        try
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(true);
            timer.schedule(new Updater(), today.getTime(), 24*60*60*1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          log.fatal(e.getLocalizedMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("--> Demon: exit");
}

private class Updater extends TimerTask
{
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Updater.class);

    @Inject
    @Named("updaterService")
    private IUpdaterService updaterService;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        log.info("Task: update records (start)");

        List<Record> list = updaterService.getAll();//<-- This throws the exception
        for(Record item : list)
        {
            updaterService.update(item);
        }

        log.info("Task: update records (exit)");
    }   
}
```

The error is

`Exception in thread "Timer-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at test.service.impl.DemonImpl$Updater.run(DemonImpl.java:66)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)`

The application works fine except for this class. How can I inject the service when the application is fully working?

Comment: if you want injected fields or methods to BE instanced , then its not the right way to call the bean with new Bean() , cause the platform is not handling the current bean

Comment: Since CDI uses proxies and introspection, I'm not confident a `private` class would be accessible to the CDI context. You will be better served by injecting into the `DemonImpl` and then accessing that from the `Updater`

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work as a private class. I have moved the code to a new class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you have a NPE when the Class is not a CDI Bean. If you make new Updater() this is not considered by CDI. you have to @Inject the Updater in your Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

CDI won't manage the instance since you instantiate your `Updater` by calling the constructor of it yourself.

Now there are two ways to fix this:

1. Inject an instance of the `Updater` class in `DemonImpl` and use that one.
2. Create a new CDI managed instance at runtime by injecting a `Provider<Updater>` instance in `DemonImpl` and get a new instance of the `Updater` class from it.